# Interior $H^2$ regularity (proof)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, regularity-theory-of-pdes, partial-differential-equations

The problem is related to the proof of the interior $H^2$ regularity theorem from Evans's book *Partial Differential Equations* (sec 6.3).

In the proof, I am having difficulty in understanding how the following inequality was deduced,

$$|A_2|\leq C \int_U \zeta |D_k^hDu||D_k^hu| + \zeta|D_k^hDu||Du| + \zeta|D_k^hu||Du|dx,$$
where
$$
A_2 = \sum_{i,j=1}^n \int_U [a^{ij,h}D_k^hDuD_k^hu2\zeta D\zeta + (D_k^ha^{ij}) D_k^hDu\zeta^2 + (D_k^ha^{ij}) D_k^hu2\zeta D\zeta   ]dx
$$
and $D_k^h$ is the difference quotient.

I thought triangular inequality for integrals was used here, but I do not understand how terms like $\zeta^2$ disappears.

I am also having difficulty in understanding on how after application of Cauchy's inequality, the Integral space changes from $U$ to $W$?

Here are snapshots to the [Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQYAr.png) and [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoUMd.png).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: $2z Dz = D(z^2)$, so integrating by parts you will find other terms with $z^2$ which might cancel the already existing one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope the following clarifications help: you want to bound
$$
a^{ij,h}D_k^hu_{x_i}D_k^hu2\zeta\zeta_{x_j}+\left(D_k^ha^{ij}\right)u_{x_i}D_k^hu_{x_j}\zeta^2+\left(D_k^ha^{ij}\right)u_{x_i}D_h^ku2\zeta\zeta_{x_j}=I_1+I_2+I_3.
$$
I dropped the summation signs and the integrals since they are not playing any role right now. Also, careful with how you wrote $A_2$, since you don't have full gradient but rather partial derivatives on $u$ and $\zeta$ and more importantly you are missing a $u_{x_i}$ in the last two terms.

Now, we now that $a^{ij}\in C^1(U)$ with implies uniform bounds on $a^{ij,h}$ and $D_k^ha^{ij}$ (by Section 5.8.2 in Evans' book). Also, $0\leq\zeta\leq 1$ (which implies $\zeta^2\leq\zeta$) and 
$|\nabla \zeta|$ is of the order of $\frac{1}{\text{dist}(V,\mathbb{R}^n\setminus W)}$. And of course, $|D_k^hu_{x_i}|\leq|D_k^hDu|$. This readily yields
$$
|I_1|\leq C_1\zeta|D_k^hDu||D_k^hu|, \quad |I_2|\leq C_2\zeta|D_k^hDu||Du|,\quad |I_3|\leq C_3\zeta|D_k^hDu||Du|
$$
where $C_k,k=1,2,3$ are universal constants. Then you just take $C=\max_{k=1,2,3}\{C_k\}$ sum over $i,j$ and integrate to get the desired bound.

As for the integral space, it's not written in the clearest of ways, but the idea is that you have, say $\int_{U}\zeta|D_k^hDu||D_k^hu|\:dx$. Since $\zeta$ vanishes outside $W$ you can write
$$
\int_{U}\zeta|D_k^hDu||D_k^hu|\:dx=\int_{W}\zeta|D_k^hDu||D_k^hu|\:dx\leq \epsilon\int_{W}\zeta^2|D_k^hDu|^2\:dx+\frac{1}{4\epsilon}\int_W|D_k^hu|^2\:dx
$$ 
but $\zeta^2|D_k^hDu|^2\geq 0$ so I can integrate in the larger domain $U$, therefore
$$
\int_{U}\zeta|D_k^hDu||D_k^hu|\:dx\leq \epsilon\int_{U}\zeta^2|D_k^hDu|^2\:dx+\frac{1}{4\epsilon}\int_W|D_k^hu|^2\:dx
$$ 
the point being that you want the first integral in the whole domain to absorb it with the left hand side and the second integral in $W$ so you can apply the bound on the difference quotients. Applying this idea you get the desired bounds.

Does all of this make sense?

Comment: Ah I think I understand (I will have to read more carefully before I award the bounty). I was confused because I thought that $C$ ought to not depend on $\zeta$.

Comment: I understand. As a remark,  the important thing about $C$ is that it doesn't depend on $u$ itself. Dependence on $\zeta$ is expected as this function is used as a cut-off, so it really means that your constant depends on the inner domain $W$ (notice that the closer $\partial W$ is to $\partial U$ the bigger $C$ gets). That cannot be avoided as you don't assume anything on the boundary values of $u$, and that's why these are called interior regularity results. There are global regularity results following in Evans' book and excellent references for further reading at the end of the chapter.

Comment: Yes, in hindsight now I see. Of course it has to depend on $\zeta$, because this is just another way of saying it depends on $W$ (which is obviously necessary). Thank you!